# Коза ---> козёл

Tags: этимология

Что это за странный словообразовательный элемент "ел", почему он присутствует только в слове козёл?

Answer (score 3):

Осел – ослица – осленок, орел – орлица - орленок, козел – козленок…

В этом ряду словообразующий элемент «ел» встречается шесть раз и его следует считать закономерным. А вот «коза» то и является исключительным образованием, поскольку называться ей надлежало бы «козлицей».